# Why does my C# Xml code only work when I enumerate variable enumerable

Tags: c#, enumerate, enumerable, xml-attribute, xmllist

I am working on code that formats an XML file so that subfolder nodes are actually nested within their parent node. The source XML has every folder as a separate childnode in the root instead of the proper tree as you would expect it to be with subfolders in their main folders. The piece of code this question is about:

```
// Load original XML

string sFile = "PathFile";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(sFile);

var n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes ("//*");   // Load all nodes into nodelist n
// int nCount = n.Count;                           // If uncommented code works

foreach(XmlNode x in n)
{ rest of the code }
```

Now I have the code working properly, but only sometimes, even without changing anything in between runs. I have narrowed it down to this: When debugging the code in Visual Studio it goes wrong if I just run the code from beginning to end. If I break halfway and take a look at the attributes in the XmlNodelist n (by hovering over it with the cursor and seeing the element count) it does work. 
After discovering this I added the

```
int nCount = n.Count;
```

line and now the code works when running unsupervised from start to finish.

What is happening here and what is the correct way to address this issue? Note: doc.LoadXml does not work with this particular file.

Thank you loads,

Thomas

Comment: Does following work? : XmlNode[] n = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes ("//*").ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng `XmlNodeList` does not have a `.ToArray()` method, nor can you call the Linq `.ToArray()` extension method on it because it does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Because of side-effects in the implementation of `XmlNodeList`.

`XmlNode.SelectNodes()` returns an `XmlNodeList` (technically, an [`XPathNodeList`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XPathNodeList.cs,d4cb3d95fb105461)), which is a "live list" of the nodes matching the selection (in this case an XPath selection).

As you iterate the `XPathNodeList` or access it in other ways, it makes its way through the matching nodes, building up an internal list as needed, and returning them as needed.

So if you try to rearrange the document as you are iterating through the nodes, this can foul up the iteration and cause it to stop before you have gone through all of them. The iteration is basically chasing a moving target as the document shifts underneath it.

However, in order to return a value for the `Count` property, the `XPathNodeList` basically needs to find every matching node and count them, so it goes through the entire set of matches and places them all in the internal list.

```
public override int Count {
    get {
        if (! done) {
            ReadUntil(Int32.MaxValue);
        }
        return list.Count;
    }
}
```

I think this explains what you are seeing. When you access the `Count` property before making changes, it builds up the entire list of nodes, as a side-effect, so that list is still populated when you actually iterate through them.

Of course, it would not be wise to rely on this undocumented behavior.

Instead, I advise that you actually copy the contents of the `XmlNodeList` to a list of your own, and then iterate over that:

```
string sFile = "PathFile";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(sFile);

var allNodes = doc.DocumentElement
    .SelectNodes("//*")
    .OfType<XmlNode>()      // using System.Linq;
    .ToList();

foreach (XmlNode x in allNodes)
{
    // rest of the code 
}
```

Comment: My recommendations.  Never use 'var' unless you have to.

Comment: Good job on the usage of `var` here. It's clear from the code that a `List<XmlNode>` will be declared.

Comment: @jdweng I've been using C# for 12 years and am quite satisfied with my use of `var`. And do you really think you're going to change someone's coding style without even providing any reasoning for your advice?

Comment: This is about as perfect an answer as I could hope for thank you! Very clear as to what went wrong. I tried your solution and it worked, very happy not to use the undocumented behaviour like you said. Diving a little deeper into your answer does the fact that the XmlNodeList is live also mean that changes made to XmlNodes in that list are automatically reflected in the source XmlDocument? Because I spent a lot of time building out dynamic xPaths to reflect changes made in the foreach loop back to the XmlDocument. Turned out for the best if I can't use a live list in the end though.

Comment: @ThomasW `XmlNode`s are mutable objects, and any changes made to them will be reflected in the original `XmlDocument`. That is true regardless of what you use to iterate through them. Hard to picture exactly how you're going about modifying the document, but if you share your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and post a link to the question here, I might be able to suggest some improvements.

Comment: I know what my college teacher would give me as a grade if I used 'var' when I could specify the type.

Comment: @jdweng I suppose we should all write code in a way that would please your college teacher. I imagine he or she must burst a blood vessel at the sight of JavaScript code.

Comment: It is not the language, but the people who write the code.  Any code written should use variables that are descriptive and code the is well documented and is easy to read.  Choosing the right compiler makes a difference : https://www.educba.com/java-compilers/

Comment: @JLRishe Yes I would be very interested to see what improvements could be made. I must warn that I am an absolute novice at coding and this code is copmletely Frankenstein-ed together. I'll try to get it on code review but right now all descriptions are in Dutch and without descriptions it is hard to track through I think. Also have to check it for proprietary information. I'll try and do it today and let you know!

Comment: @JLRishe Here it is! https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244039/xml-tree-reformatter-requested-code-c